# Codificación URL safe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

Estoy desarrollando un servicio de mensajería por e-mail con Python. Desde una tarea programada envío la información del correo que se va a enviar, la cual viene codificada en base64 con URL safe. Recibo la información correctamente, la tengo como una variable porque me imprime la cadena codificada. Quisiera saber como puedo decodificar esta cadena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso es recomendado definir una función para procesar la decodificación de la información como la necesitas, yo suelo usar esta que es muy sencilla:

```
import base64

def decoBase64UrlSafe(s):
    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s + '=' * (4 - len(s) % 4))
```

y la puedes usar de la siguiente manera:

```
MENSAJE = decoBase64UrlSafe(datoCodificado)
```

Con esto decodificas UrlSafe teniendo en cuenta que el dato viene de Base64.

Espero sea de tu utilidad.